# how to create an invoice in pdf with barcode in django

Tags: python, django

i want to create an invoice in pdf format with barcode,
first mybarcode.py file to create barcode using reportlab

# mybarcode.py file to create barecode

```
    from reportlab.lib.units import mm
    from reportlab.graphics.barcode import createBarcodeDrawing
    from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing, String
    from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts import HorizontalBarChart

    class MyBarcodeDrawing(Drawing):
            def __init__(self, text_value, *args, **kw):
                barcode = createBarcodeDrawing('Code128', value=text_value,  barHeight=19*mm, humanReadable=True)
                Drawing.__init__(self,barcode.width,barcode.height,*args,**kw)
                self.add(barcode, name='barcode')
```

views function to generate pdf with barcode.

# views.py

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.tables import Table
cm = 2.54

def print_pdf(request):

  import mybarcode
  product = Product.objects.get(id = id)
  d = mybarcode.MyBarcodeDrawing(product.code)
  binaryStuff = d.asString('jpg')

  response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
  filename=somefilename.pdf'
  elements = []
  doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response, rightMargin=0, leftMargin=6.5 * cm, topMargin=0.3 * cm, bottomMargin=0)

  data=[("barcode", binaryStuff),("name", "some_name")]
  table = Table(data)
  elements.append(table)
  doc.build(elements)
  return response
```

and getting this error : 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your issues:

```
    import codecs

    f = codecs.open(dir+location, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    txt = f.read()
```

from that moment txt is in unicode format and you can use it everywhere in your code.

If you want to generate UTF-8 files after your processing do:

```
    f.write(txt.encode('utf-8'))
```